# How to extract data from .iq file?

Tags: gnuradio, qpsk

I am trying to extract data from .iq file recorded by radio. The modulation is QPSK. I have implemented a GRC flow graph but the costas loop is not converging. Can anyone please help in understanding the issue[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [What is the file format of a file_sink? How can I read files produced by a file sink?](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=File_Sink#What_is_the_file_format_of_a_file_sink?_How_can_I_read_files_produced_by_a_file_sink?)

Comment: but you're asking two different questions in one question post. You might want to ask, in much much more detail even, about the Costas Loop problem in a separate post.

Comment: I have edited the post with the blocks. I want to read the data in the iq file, not sure how to do that